# Webpack, режим разработки. Доступ к коду из файла в консоли браузера

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, webpack

Есть ли такая настройка, чтобы я писал код, он прогоняется через babel и я в консоли мог использовать переменные из файла?

Например, я создал в файле объект/переменную, а в консоли браузера мог им пользоваться? Сейчас я имею ситуацию, когда у меня в коде есть объекты.переменные, но консоль их не видит. Чтобы посмотреть их мне приходится в файле их выводить в консоль. Примерная ситуация на скрине.

В галпе вроде все было как надо, но тут тоже ведь такое должно быть возможно

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: вебпак каждый файл в функцию запихивает для импорта, поэтому все переменные закрыты в области видимости

Comment: Записывай свой объект в свойство глобального объекта.